# Separating Form and Processing in Python

Tags: python, html, forms, post, cgi

I'm using the `cgi` module to handle form input data, but I would like to have the form and the processing in separate files (modules?). Is there a way to pass the `POST`ed information from the HTML to the processing file?

I'm not using any frameworks and would like to keep this as simple as possible. I know that I can get this to work by having the HTML printed in the python file, but I'd like to keep the two separate.

Here's the real problem code:

```
<form action="processes/process.py" method="post">
            <div id="name1" class="formData"><label for="">First name:</label><input name="firstName" type="text" id="firstName" /></div>
            <div id="name2" class="formData"><label>Last name:</label><input name="lastName" type="text" id="lastName" /></div>
            <div id="email" class="formData"><label>Email address:</label><input name="emailAddress" type="text" id="emailAddress" /></div>
            <div id="mailAddress" class="formData"><label>Mailing address:</label><input name="physicalAddress" type="textarea" id="physicalAddress" /></div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="T_validateForm('firstName','','R','lastName','','R','EmailAddress','','RisEmail');return document.T_returnValue">
        </form>
```

I can have this printed in my process.py file and change the action, but I would like this form code to be separate from the code I will use to manage and distribute the information form the form. I need to pass the data to process.py

I'm trying to get the data in the python code here:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
firstName = form['firstName'].value
lastName = form['lastName'].value
emailAddress = form['emailAddress'].value
physicalAddress = form['physicalAddress'].value
```

I know that in php `form` is replaced by `$_POST`. Is there a similar identifier in python? `form` works when they're in the same file, but it seems that there should be some way to tell python to get the data from the HTML `POST`. I thought that `cgi.FieldStorage()` did that, but it doesn't work. Should I be passing parameters to `cgi.FieldStorage()`?

Comment: Your question is a little too open ended. Please post some code that you've tried with pointers to what you'd like to change

Comment: Edited. Anything else I should add?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what exactly your question is. Are you maybe looking for a templating language like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org), [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) or [Chameleon](http://chameleon.repoze.org/)? Or a simple form generation and validation library like [FormEncode](http://www.formencode.org/)?

Comment: Further research seems to indicate that this isn't built into Python as it is in PHP. Basically, I need to save user input as variables and then access them in another Python module. Should I just edit the question to ask this somewhat basic question?

Comment: Perfect! Could you answer with this so that I can credit you, Lukas?

Comment: Ok, merged my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is pretty broad, altough I understand separating content, logic and presentation is what you're after.

Are you maybe looking for a templating language like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) or [Chameleon](http://chameleon.repoze.org/)? Or a simple form generation and validation library like [FormEncode](http://www.formencode.org/)? Those can be just as easily used with or without a web framework.

As opposed to PHP, in Python CGI is hardly ever used. We use [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) instead, or web frameworks (micro to large) with their own request model and form handling libraries. Doing it yourself with CGI could be an educational example, but you'll almost always be better of using an existing framework even for small web apps. Could be a micro framework like [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/).

If it's unclear to you how to factor out code into several Python modules, I would ask a new question about that (probably best with no ties to web development whatsoever). Additionally, I'd evaluate a couple templating languages for Python, and possibly a few [micro frameworks](http://pyvideo.org/video/983/web-micro-framework-battle).

Comment: I'm looking into Flask to do this, as its documentation seems to suggest that it was designed with Web development in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Flask is definitely a good choice, simple but already includes many things you'll need in most web development projects.